# Read first party cookie using flash/AS3

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, cookies

Is it possible to read first party cookies from flash?

It should be noted that we have complete access to javascript via the `ExternalInterface` class.

So, now the question is - can we access first party cookie from javascript? Our javascript code will be loaded by a website which is not hosted by us. This makes the cookies created by that website - first party cookies. How can we access these "first" party cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as long as you have access to the javascript that is going to be reading and writing the cookies using the external interface then it is really just a javascript problem.

This page may be useful to you:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Whatever domain the javascript & flash application is served from will be the domain that owns the cookies.